# Next.js/React 18, Google Maps JS API not clearing prior map state

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js

I have a React 18/Next.js app that has a Google Map.

I have a shared Map component that I pass in map-related objects to to map, currently an array of latLng coordinates, that I used to generate directions. The order of this array is managed outside the Map component.

Lets say i pass in an array of 2 coordinates (A, B) to get the directions. What im seeing is on the initial "load" of the Map (after a refresh of the browser) - the coordinates plot correctly w/ the single route line going from A -> B.

However, when i now change the order of the coordinates to be [ B, A ] (which will make B the directions origin and A the destination), the Google map is updated, and it draws the route from B -> A, however the OLD route (A -> B) still displays on the map. I checked the response, and both (A->B and B->A) have a single route. Refreshing the browser renders the single route. Also, if I add more coordinates to the props list, they show up on the map (w/ the new route poly lines), but if i remove a waypoint - it doesnt remove that marker. It's like I can only add to the map, and cannot remove from it.

Any ideas?

```
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import useDeepCompareEffect from "use-deep-compare-effect";
import { GoogleMap, DirectionsRenderer, MarkerF } from "@react-google-maps/api";

export function MarkerMap({ markers }) {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */ (null));
  const [directionsResponse, setDirectionsResponse] = useState(null);

  const center = markers[0];

  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    console.log("markers changed", markers);
    async function getDirections() {
      const directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
      const response = await directionsService.route({
        origin: markers[0],
        destination: markers[markers.length < 2 ? 0 : markers.length - 1],
        travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        optimizeWaypoints: false,
        waypoints:
          markers.length > 2
            ? markers.slice(1, -1).map((m) => ({ location: m, stopover: true }))
            : [],
      });
      setDirectionsResponse(response);
    }
    if (markers?.length > 1) {
      getDirections();
    }
  }, [markers]);

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      center={center}
      zoom={13}
      onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
      onUnmount={() => setMap(null)}
    >
      {directionsResponse && (
        <DirectionsRenderer
          options={{
            preserveViewport: true,
            draggable: false,
            hideRouteList: false,
            suppressMarkers: false,
            map: map,
            routeIndex: 0,
            polylineOptions: {
              map: map,
              strokeColor: "#FF0000",
              strokeWeight: 4,
            },
            suppressBicyclingLayer: true,
            suppressPolylines: false,
            markerOptions: {
              label: "Sup dude",
            },
          }}
          directions={directionsResponse}
        />
      )}

      {!directionsResponse &&
        markers?.map((marker, i) => <MarkerF key={i} position={marker} />)}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that i can't use the  component.
Instead I have to manually create a ref of the DirectionsRenderer object, and use that throughout the life of my component.

So...

```
const directionsRenderer = useRef(new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer());
...
useEffect(() => { 
   .. look stuff up using the directions service.

   directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
   directionsRenderer.setDirections(directionsResponse);

});
```

The problem seems to be that (i guess, as youd expect) when you call `new google.maps.Whatever()` it creates a new instance of the class, and any prior instances are not "disconnected" .. so you just keep adding directions to the map. If you keep track of prior instances, you can setMap(null) on them to remove their side-effects from the map - but it seems simpler/more common to just get a ref of the object, and update that same ref as state changes.